# Group By in elasticsearch 1.3.1 using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm new in elastic search, I'm trying to do "group by" using aggregation (min,max,avg,sum,count), I'm using elasticsearch 1.3.1, column names and values are coming from DB, manually created object for now.

I am stuck in an infinite loop can any one help? Here is my code:

```
  SoftP p1 =new SoftP();
            SoftP p2 =new SoftP();
            SoftP p3 =new SoftP();
            SoftP p4 =new SoftP();

            p1.setCol("quantity");
            p2.setCol("quantity");
            p3.setCol("quantity");
            p4.setCol("quantity");

            p1.setInputboxValue("100");
            p2.setInputboxValue("200");
            p3.setInputboxValue("300");
            p4.setInputboxValue("400");

            List<SoftP>testListj=new ArrayList<SoftP>();
            testListj.add(p1);
            testListj.add(p2);
            testListj.add(p3);
            testListj.add(p4);
            MinBuilder orderByMin=null;
            for(SoftP s:testListj){

             orderByMin= AggregationBuilders.min(s.getInputboxValue()).field(s.getCol());
            }
            Client client=null;
            SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch()
                    .setQuery( QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery() )
                    .addAggregation( orderByMin )
                    .execute().actionGet();


            System.out.println("sr>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+sr);
```

Comment: better to output that ES query getting build in SearchResponse sr , and see what the actual query is that you are hitting ES with.

Comment: I tried another way                                               try { 
              response = node.client().prepareSearch() 
                .setQuery( query.should(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()) )
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("quantity")).execute().actionGet(); 
          } catch (Throwable e) { } 
          Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>(); 
          for (SearchHit hit : response.getHits()) { 
              Long id = hit.field("id").<Long>getValue(); 
              result.add(String.valueOf(id)); 
          } System.out.println(response);

Comment: getting this output::{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "successful" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}

Comment: in my opinion you should call ES with the properly built query in JSON rather than trying to set the query using the library, you are not sure what is being built by the library. open a console and hit ES with JSON directly first build a query and then do a get request and show output.